# Can't get the next JFrame to pop up

Tags: java, swing, loops, jframe

I'm making the game of battleship and I can't get the JFrame with the win panel nor the JFrame with the lose panel to pop up when the player wins or loses. Any ideas why? I'm thinking it just never gets to the other two loops in the main program, but I'm not sure. I did check to make sure that the global variables correct and incorrect were incrementing correctly, and they are.

//Battleship.java

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

 public class Battleship
{
public static String name;

public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException
{

Battleship.name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is your name?");

String answer = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Welcome to Battleship, "+name+". Would you      like instructions?"); //(GUI1) Dialog Box

if(answer.equals ("yes") || answer.equals ("Yes"))
{
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"In this variant of Battleship, you will try to   bomb two randomly-placed ships"
                                  +"\nby clicking on the buttons that represent the field of play. There are two ships:"
                                  +"\nOne 1x2 ship and one 1x3 ship. Green is a hit and  red is a miss. Good luck!");
}




//Creates a JFrame and adds the Buttons panel to it    
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Battleship");
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

Buttons b = new Buttons(); //(GUI2)  1-D Array of Buttons
Check c = new Check();
NamePanel n = new NamePanel();
JPanel panel = new JPanel(); //Instantiating a panel
panel.add(c);
panel.add(b); //Adds the 1-D Array of buttons to the panel
panel.setBackground(Color.blue);
panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
frame.getContentPane().add (panel);
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
frame.getContentPane().validate();
frame.getContentPane().repaint();

 if(Buttons.correct == 5 && (Buttons.incorrect+Buttons.correct)<=15)
 {
//Creats a new frame and adds the winner's panel to the frame 
JFrame frame1 = new JFrame("Winner!");
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

WinPanel panel2 = new WinPanel();
frame1.getContentPane().add(panel2);
frame1.pack();
frame1.setVisible(true);
}

else if(Buttons.correct<5 && (Buttons.incorrect+Buttons.correct) >= 15)
{
 //Creates a new frame and adds the loser's panel to the frame
 JFrame frame1 = new JFrame("You lost");
 frame1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

 LosePanel panel2 = new LosePanel();
 frame1.getContentPane().add(panel2);
 frame1.pack();
 frame1.setVisible(true);
  }
  }
 }
```

//Buttons.java

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.*;

public class Buttons extends JPanel 
{
JButton[] btn; 
static int[] numbers = new int[5];
public static int correct = 0;
public static int incorrect = 0;


  public Buttons() throws IOException
 {
String[] numberLine = choose(new File("Coords.txt")).split(",");

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
numbers[i] = Integer.parseInt(numberLine[i]);
        }


btn = new JButton[25];

setLayout(new GridLayout(5,5));

setBackground(Color.blue);
setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,300));


ButtonListener blisten = new ButtonListener(); //LI

  for(int i=0;i<25;i++)
  {
  btn[i] = new JButton();
  btn[i].addActionListener(blisten);
  add (btn[i]);
  }

} //Ends Constructor

private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener
 {


 public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event)
  {
  Object source = event.getSource();
  while((Buttons.correct+Buttons.incorrect)<15 && (Buttons.correct<5))
  {
  for(int i=0;i<25;i++)
    if(source==btn[i])
      if(i==numbers[0] || i==numbers[1] || i==numbers[2] || i==numbers[3] ||      i==numbers[4])
  {
    btn[i].setBackground(Color.green);
    btn[i].setEnabled(false);
    Buttons.correct++;
    System.out.println(Buttons.correct);
    }
    else
    {
    btn[i].setBackground(Color.red);
    btn[i].setEnabled(false);
    Buttons.incorrect++;
    System.out.println(Buttons.incorrect);
    }
    break;
  }



  }
}


//Choose method to choose a random line of the imported text file
public static String choose(File f) throws FileNotFoundException 
{
 String result = null; //String is set to null
 Random rand = new Random(); //Instantiating a random number generator
 int n = 0;
 for(Scanner sc = new Scanner(f); sc.hasNext(); ) //for loop-as long as the file has   more to read
 {
    ++n; //Incrementing temp variable
    String line = sc.nextLine(); //Reading from the file
    if(rand.nextInt(n) == 0)
       result = line; //String result is now equal to the text imported from the file         
 }

 return result; //Returning the string      
}

 } //Ends Program
 // LosePanel.java
 import javax.swing.*;
 import java.awt.*;

 public class LosePanel extends JPanel
 {
 public LosePanel()
 {
setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,500));
setBackground(Color.white);
}
    public void paintComponent(Graphics page) //DR
  {
  super.paintComponent(page);

page.drawOval(165,165,150,150);
 page.fillOval(165+47,165+25,10,10);
page.fillOval(165+92,165+25,10,10);

 page.drawArc(165+45,165+80,60,30,0,180);



 page.drawString("Better luck next time", 182,90);
 }
}
```

// WinPanel.java

```
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.*;

    public class WinPanel extends JPanel
    {
     public WinPanel()
     {
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,500));
    setBackground(Color.white);
    }
      public void paintComponent(Graphics page) //(DR)
    { 
      super.paintComponent(page);

    page.drawOval(165,165,150,150);
    page.fillOval(165+47,165+25,10,10);
    page.fillOval(165+92,165+25,10,10);

    page.drawArc(165+46,165+70,60,30,0,-180);

    page.drawString("You've won the game! Congratulations!", 150,90);
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

Guis are event driven frame works.  That is, the user does something and you respond to it

Basically, what's happening, is you're checking the state of `Buttons` before anythings actually being done.

Take a look at [Creating a GUI in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/), [How to use buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) and [How to write an Action Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) for some ideas, examples and suggestions on writing GUI's